# Which MySQL statements require the use of a MySqlDataReader object?

Tags: c#, mysql

When accessing a MySQL server programmatically, there are two types of statement:

- A statement (such as `SELECT`) that returns a resultset, and requires the use of a `MySqlDataReader`;
- A statement (such as `UPDATE`) that does not return a resultset and therefore can be executed via a `MySqlCommand` object without a `MySqlDataReader`

Using a `MySqlCommand` on a statement that returns a resultset causes an exception from the MySQL driver, and likewise the same thing happens when a `MySqlDataReader` is used with a statement that does not return a resultset.

In order to have one function that can execute both types of statement, I need to filter what statements need to use a `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader`. My plan is to create an array which contains statements such as `SELECT` that needs to be dealt with `MySqlDataReader`, for example this pseudocode:

```
MySqlResultSet ExecuteStatement(string statement)
{
    string[] statementTypes = { "SELECT", "SHOW", };
    foreach (statementType = statementTypes)
    {
        if (statement.find(statementType){
            //MySqlCommand
            //Returns null.
        }
        else
        {
            //MySqlDataReader
            //Returns the reader
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's a big charade going on here, and your question isn't as silly as it seems - here's what returns data which is usually represented by most languages as some sort of usable construct:

- `SELECT` (which you know how to use)
- `SHOW` (for example, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%'` or `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable`)
- `DESCRIBE` example: `DESCRIBE yourtable`;

Disclaimer: these are the ones that I can remember at this point, there could be more, please feel free to update the list if I've missed anything.